# Mocking official MongoDb driver

Tags: mongodb, unit-testing, go, mocking

I need to define these interfaces to mock official mongo driver

```
type MgCollection interface {   
    FindOne(ctx context.Context, filter interface{}, opts ...*options.FindOneOptions) *mongo.SingleResult
    // Other methods
}

type MgDatabase interface {
    Collection(name string, opts ...*options.CollectionOptions) MgCollection
    // Other methods
}
```

In mongo driver package there are two structs **mongo.Collection** and **mongo.Database** with these methods

```
func (coll *Collection) FindOne(ctx context.Context, filter interface{}, opts ...*options.FindOneOptions) *SingleResult {
    // Method code
}

func (db *Database) Collection(name string, opts ...*options.CollectionOptions) *Collection {
    // Method code
}
```

The struct ***mongo.Collection** implement **MgCollection** correctly, so this code compiles without error

```
var col mgdriver.MgCollection
col = &mongo.Collection{}
col.FindOne(ctx, nil, nil)
```

But The struct ***mongo.Database** not implement **MgDatabase**, so I when I write something like this:

```
var db mgdriver.MgDatabase
db = &mongo.Database{}
db.Collection("Test", nil)
```

Compiler show this error:

> cannot use &mongo.Database literal (type *mongo.Database) as type
>   mgdriver.MgDatabase in assignment:    *mongo.Database does not implement
>   mgdriver.MgDatabase (wrong type for Collection method)        have
>   Collection(string, ...*options.CollectionOptions) *mongo.Collection
>         want Collection(string, ...*options.CollectionOptions)
>   mgdriver.MgCollection

Both **mongo.Collection** and **mongo.Database** are in the official package and I cannot change any code in that package. so how can I change my interfaces to mock official mongo driver correctly?

Answer (score 13):

Usually, you do not. What you should do is to define a data access interface,

```
type CRUD interface {
  Create(yourModel) error
  Read(page, size, skip) []yourModel
  Update(yourModel) error
  Delete(yourModel) error
}
```

and implement it.

You then mock the interface, for example with [testify/mock](https://github.com/stretchr/testify#mock-package):

```
type MockedCRUD struct {
  mock.Mock
}

func(m *MockedCRUD)Create(y yourModel) error{
  returned m.Called(y).Error(0)
}
// And so on and so forth
```

Since `MockedCRUD` satisfies the CRUD interface, you can use it as you would use your `MongoCRUD` implementation, without any hassle:

```
func TestYourApplicationLogicCallingCreate( t *testing.T){
    model := YourModel{Type: ”Baz”})

    mocked := new(MockedCRUD)
    mocked.On(”Create”,model).Return(ErrInvalidType)

    app := YourApplication{CRUD:mocked}

    err := app.yourApplicationLogicCallingCreate(model)

    assert.Error(t,err)
    assert.Equal(t,ErrInvalidType,err)

}
```

Remains the question how do you test the implementation of the CRUD interface. I used to use the mgo driver, originally developed by Gustavo Niemeyer and taken over by globalsign. That brought a nifty little package called [dbtest](https://godoc.org/github.com/globalsign/mgo/dbtest). It is actually a very thin wrapper around a MongoDB instance, starting and stopping one on demand, with the ability to reset the data in between tests. Either just import `dbtest` or, to quote a Go Proverb

> A little bit of copy is better than a little bit of dependency.

(Remember to give credit, though, and retain the copyright notes.)

So, using the method described above you can do your unit tests pretty fast against a mock, with stable and predictable answers tailored to your tests and only do relatively expensive and slow tests against MongoDB only where you absolutely must.

Added bonus: it is relatively easy to swap out your actual persistence technology.

Comment: As you mentioned I defined an interface for CRUD, so I can mock CRUD operation in upper layers. But my question was about writing tests for CRUD operations.  I decide to use official mongo driver, It does not contain something like dbtest.

Comment: @VahidJafari You can still `import github.com/globalsign/mgo/dbtest` in your tests. Or do a little bit of copy, as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

In case if anyone still needs the interfaces, I implemented a simple wrapper to provide the interfaces for all main classes. Please see the [GitHub project](https://github.com/sv-tools/mongoifc).

It has the interfaces for such objects as:

- Client
- Database
- Session
- ChangeStream
- Cursor
- Collection
- SingleResult
- IndexView

The main problem is that it requires the use of the wrapper instead of a direct object.